# Writing untagged YAML with Ruby Psych, then reading It

Tags: ruby

I have Ruby using Psych that writes YAML like this:

```
---
- !ruby/struct:Dhc::QueryEvent
  time: 2018-01-02T07:45:18.470Z
  hits: 2525
  qtime: 13
  server: search1
  q: search term
  searched_in:
  - productA
  - productB
  - productC
```

Is there a way I can write the YAML without the "`!ruby/struct:Dhc::QueryEvent`" tag? I want the storage formatted so it is not dependent on my `struct:Dhc::QueryEvent` for reading. In other words, I want others to have the flexibility to read the YAML however they want. Currently, they get

```
undefined class/module Dhc:: (ArgumentError)
```

Then, when I'm reading the file myself, is there a configuration in Psych that allows me to read the untagged records into my `Dhc::QueryEvent` struct? I assume this would be something like

```
ar = []
Psych.parse_stream(yaml_stream) do |node|
  ar << Dhc::QueryEvent.new(node.time, node.hits, etc...)
end
```

but maybe there is a shorter way?

Comment: Call `#to_h` on the struct before storing it.

Comment: Also, your current code should be written as: `Psych.parse_stream(yaml_stream).map { |node| Dhc::QueryEvent.new(node.time, node.hits, etc...) }`.